# addToSet mongo update document

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

I have two schemas.

`tables.js`:

```javascript
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SchemaOne = new Schema({
    TheDate: { type: String },
    ThePiece: {type: String }
}, { versionKey: false });

var SchemaTwo = new Schema({
    UrlLink: { type: String },
    Name: { type: String },
    Type: { type: String },
    Thing: { type: String },
    NewInfo: [SchemaOne]
}, { versionKey: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('tables', SchemaTwo);
```

I then import the file above:

```javascript
var ThisTable = require("../models/tables.js");
```

I then try to update `NewInfo` object (if some conditions are met):

```javascript
ThisTable.update({ UrlLink: Myurl }, {
    $addToSet: {
       "NewInfo": {
           TheDate: ThisDate,
           ThePiece: ThisPiece
        }
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because the script crashes and I can't debug because of some restrictions on remote computer.

Comment: You need to give `update` a callback function, but other than that it should work.

Comment: *"I can't debug because of some restrictions on remote computer"* - You should really consider to set up a proper local test environment on your own computer. You can not develop properly when you can not debug properly. The time invested in a proper environment amortizes itself really quickly.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I do : return next(); after the last parenthesis. Is it correct?